# How to modify input stream in Javacc?

Tags: parsing, javacc

Is there a way in which we can modify the input stream during parsing using Javacc ? I have a use case where I want to replace a token with a string during parsing and then parse that replaced string.

For example,

```
define var $x="2*2";
evaluate $x;
```

So, during parsing when I encounter any token that starts with $ like $x in this case, I should do an inline replacement and then parse it normally using Javacc.

So, from the above example, it means I should be parsing the following statement after inline replacement :

```
evaluate "2*2";
```

Is this possible in Javacc ? Can we modify the input stream, so that on seeing a special token I append its inline replacement to the input stream ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to do this is to do a preprocessing pass before parsing begins -- this is how C compilers generally work.  If you must do it during parsing, then you would need to use a custom input stream -- see the documentation on how to do that. And you would have to be very careful about lookahead.